# JSON formatter lib

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm looking for a way to format (as in whitespace, newlines where suitable) a JSON result so that I can display the actual result but well formatted.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Send",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(request),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#ResponseBody").val(data.ResponseBody);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

this is my code, which works fine `data.ResponseBody` contains the JSON, but as expected, it is not well formatted.

Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin / method that would allow me to format the response?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can simply use the third parameter of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data.ResponseBody);
        $("#ResponseBody").val(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
    },
```

Don't forget to add a CSS rule like `#ResponseBody {white-space: pre;}` to make newlines display.

Answer (score 2):

JSONLint [includes that functionality](https://github.com/umbrae/jsonlintdotcom/blob/master/c/js/jsl.format.js)

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple code to format JSON.. http://joncom.be/code/javascript-json-formatter/

Hope this will help some one..